# Setting up bash shortcut for committing to git with the current branch as message

Tags: git, bash, version-control, command-line

SO I'm trying to setup this shortcut in bashrc to commtitting to git using the current branch name as the commit message and I have this:

```
git branch | grep "*" | sed "s/* //" | git commit -m
```

but running this line would instead display the

> error: switch `m' requires a value

error....

how can I fix this such that executing this line will be equivalent to running `git commit -m "CurrentBranchName"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You were almost there, except for the `xargs`, since the message needs to be passed as a command line argument and not from `STDIN` when using the `-m` option to `git commit`.

  ```
  git branch | grep "*" | sed "s/* //" | xargs git commit -m
  ```
- An alternative that should also work without using `xargs`:

  ```
  git branch | grep "*" | sed "s/* //" | git commit -F -
  ```

  The `-F` instructs `git commit` to read the commit message from a file, and `-` indicates that the file is STDIN (i.e. the output of the pipe from `sed`).